# Javascript event.preventDefault(); does not work even with delegated event

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to prevent default form's submitting behavior on my dynamically generated forms, but event.preventDefault(); does not work even with delegated event (.on). This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/><br>");
    // I am adding 2 new forms there:
    var topic = $( '<form action = "#" method = "POST" name="new_topic" id="new_topic">'+ document.getElementById('csrf_token').value +
                  '<textarea  name="name" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" id="new_form"></textarea></form>'+
                  '<br><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="newMygt" />');


    var summary = $('<form action = "#" method = "POST" name="new_summary" id="new_summary">'+ document.getElementById('csrf_token').value +
                    '<textarea  name="content" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" id="new_form"></textarea></form>'+
                    '<br><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="newMygt" />');


    (topic).appendTo(fieldWrapper).show('slow');
    (summary).appendTo(fieldWrapper).show('slow');
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);


});

// after clicking the '.newMygt' button the form subitms...
$('.fieldwrapper').on("click", ".newMygt",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    a = JSON.stringify($('#new_topic, #new_summary').serializeObject()); // turn that "array or smth" into JSON
    alert(a)
});
```

});

I am aware that the syntax looks like that:

$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );

But appearently I am doing something wrong and the data doesn't pop up.

**Edit: the correct answer:**

JohnP's comment:

FIX THIS - You need to bind to an element that exists when the binding is done. You were binding to the form, which is incorrect. Bind to the container

```
$('#buildyourform').on("click", ".newMygt",function(e){
..blah blah..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've listed the things you need to fix in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/a624W/1/

The two main things to fix are

1. Bad markup - You've used the same ID in multiple places and there are no closing tags for some elements.
2. Binding - You're binding to an element with the wrong selector. Even if you fix the selector, that element does not exist when the binding happens. You need to bind to the parent.

Copying the code below.

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;



    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/><br>");
    // I am adding 2 new forms there:

    /** 
FIX THIS - You use the same ID for the form. You need to make those unique. Possibly the name as well. Both forms
**/
    var topic = $('<form action = "#" method = "POST" name="new_topic" id="new_topic">' + document.getElementById('csrf_token').value +
        '<textarea  name="name" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" id="new_form"></textarea>' +
        '<br><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="newMygt" /></form>');

    var summary = $('<form action = "#" method = "POST" name="new_summary" id="new_summary">' + document.getElementById('csrf_token').value +
        '<textarea  name="content" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" id="new_form"></textarea>' +
        '<br><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="newMygt" /></form>');
    /** 
FIX THIS - Missing closing tags for both the forms
**/


    (topic).appendTo(fieldWrapper).show('slow');
    (summary).appendTo(fieldWrapper).show('slow');
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);


});

// after clicking the '.newMygt' button the form subitms...
/** 
FIX THIS - You need to bind to an element that exists when the binding is done. You were binding to the form, which is incorrect. Bind to the container. 
**/
$('#buildyourform').on("click", ".newMygt", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    a = JSON.stringify($('#new_topic, #new_summary').serialize()); //FIX THIS - The method is serizalize()
    alert(a)
});
```

Comment: @ JohnP > thank you for the very detailed answer. I have fixed the errors and the data now pops up, I will mark your answer as correct. But here's one note: I am using a custom Javascript SerializeObject() snippet that I am turning into a form field - form value dict and then I am turning that dict into into json via json.stringify(). Is there any way to parse  user entered data from dynamically added form using this snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/tB7xe/ ? Now I am getting {"name":"","content":""}

Comment: @Eimantas Have a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/a624W/2/. I've modified your click function to look at the closest form and serialize it. This works to a certain extent, but you need to modify your form add code so that it automatically generates proper IDs / names for the inputs. Otherwise the serializeObject function will keep overwriting previous values because they all have the same id / name.

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately the serializeObject() function returns an empty dict `{}` now. I have separated my current problem into a new question that can be found there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321787/javascript-parsing-dynamically-added-forms

Answer (score 1):

First, the wrong selector was being used in the code; "#" is for ID, and what you meant to use was ".", which is for selecting class:

```
$('#fieldwrapper')
```

should be

```
$('.fieldwrapper')
```

Plus, it should be noted that there are no closing form tags:

```
</form>
```

UPDATE:

Remove the "fieldwrapper" overall, instead use "document":

```
$(document).on("click", ".newMygt",function(e){
```

Realizing that the element "fieldwrapper" was also inserted after loading the page, thus failing on the event delegation.

Comment: @Kye Thank you for quick answer! I have now edited my code and added closing form tags after text areas , but the problem still exists anyway. I have tried to add closing form tags after the button, but the form still submits.

Comment: Updated the answer above. The problem is that you are adding an event listener on the element "fieldwrapper" that does not exist yet. Check out articles on event delegation of javascript for references.

Comment: Thank you for your update and for referencing some material to read, I surely need to read more about working with objects that do not exist yet to understand the "logic" of js.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate  Event Delegation is a common trick in JS to assign events to the "future" elements.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I will need to read that in order to solve the problem that I posted under JohnP's comment below.