# Javascript - parsing dynamically added forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

**How can I work with forms that have ben added dynamically ?**

Hello. I am dynamically adding forms to my page using the following code snippet. Now everything works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/><br>");
    // I am adding 2 new forms there:
    var topic = $( '<form action = "#" method = "POST" name="new_topic" id="new_topic">'+ document.getElementById('csrf_token').value +
                  '<textarea  name="name" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" id="new_form"></textarea></form>'+
                  '<br><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="newMygt" />');


    var summary = $('<form action = "#" method = "POST" name="new_summary" id="new_summary">'+ document.getElementById('csrf_token').value +
                    '<textarea  name="content" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" id="new_form"></textarea></form>'+
                    '<br><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="newMygt" />');


    (topic).appendTo(fieldWrapper).show('slow');
    (summary).appendTo(fieldWrapper).show('slow');
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);


});
```

After adding the forms I am parsing them with a great tool called [jquery-serialize-object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object/blob/master/jquery.serialize-object.js) and creating some object literals (f.ex. `{"name":"John","content":"blah blah"}`).

And then I am turning those object literals into Json with `JSON.stringify()`

Everything woorks smoothly with simple forms, but when I try to parse form that I add dynamically. I am receiving  {"name":"","content":""} data, because the form that I am parsing does not exist yet.

**The question:** Could I get some reading material or tips how could I modify the [jquery-serialize-object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object/blob/master/jquery.serialize-object.js) to parse forms that I ad dynamically ? The extension's code is a bit too complicated for me.

**EDIT:**

I found another Javascript snippet [jquery.serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON) that serializes a form into a JavaScript Object (for json.stringify()'ing it into Json later) and it seems that it is more up-to-date and it is actively developed, but I am getting completely same results with it: `{"name":"","content":""}`

**THE ANSWER:**

I actually should serialize the forms on the submit event and not on the button click. This way I will be serializing data after the user fills it in. And I should have put the  closing tag AFTER the submit buttons, not before. The working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/><br>");
    // I am adding 2 new forms there:
    var topic = $( '<form action = "#" method = "POST" name="new_topic" class="new_topic">'+ document.getElementById('csrf_token').value +
                  '<textarea id ="1" name="name" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" id="new_form"></textarea><br><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="newMygt" /></form>'
                  );


    var summary = $('<form action = "#" method = "POST" name="new_summary" class="new_summary">'+ document.getElementById('csrf_token').value +
                    '<textarea id="2" name="content" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" id="new_form"></textarea><br><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="newMygt" /></form>'
                    );


    (topic).appendTo(fieldWrapper).show('slow');
    (summary).appendTo(fieldWrapper).show('slow');
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);


});




$('#buildyourform').on('submit', 'form', function() {
    var $submittedForm = $(this); // form where you clicked submit button
    var $forms = $submittedForm.parents('.fieldwrapper').find('form'); // both forms
    var serializedForm = $forms.serializeJSON(); // serialize both forms
    var json = JSON.stringify(serializedForm);
    alert(json)
    event.preventDefault(); // do not submit the form
});
```

Now I am getting exactly what I wanted:

```
{"name":"John","content":"blah blah blah"}
```

Comment: Can you try by giving different IDs to both textareas?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! Umm I do not think that this would change anything.. I just tried it and the results are the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the plugins, both serializeJSON and serialize-object can read dynamically created forms.

I don't know how are you reading the forms later, but you need to make sure they exist at the time you are serializing them.

I created a fiddle to try out your code with [jquery.serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON): http://jsfiddle.net/vG39k/

I tried to serialize on "submit" event, and realized that you had the `input type="submit"` buttons outside the forms, so they didn't fire a submit event.

Note that in the fiddle, I put the `</form>` closing tag **AFTER** the submit buttons, not before.
That could be your problem.

HINT: use [fiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) or other similar tool to test your code ;)

Comment: Thank you for corrections and for thr tips, I will surely look into. that. But the thing that I am trying to achieve is to serialize both form's data on one button click event, like when I click a button, an alert(json) would pop up which would display {"name":"test1","content":"test2"}. Could you help me with that ?

Comment: It looks to me that what you want is to have only one form, not two forms.

Comment: I think that unfortunately two forms is exactly what I need in this particular case.. I am creating a Django framework based app for students (for summarizing lectures), one of the forms will display Topic name and the second will be Lecture's summary. And this Lecture-Summary pattern will go throughout the whole page. Now I need to be able to dynamically add those forms to the page..

Comment: Either way, if you really want to have the UI, you can use jquery.serializeJSON to serialize both forms at once. Just make sure you match both forms in your jQuery selector. This fiddle shows you how: http://jsfiddle.net/vG39k/1/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! The code works exactly as I wanted now. Thank you for your help and your time :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems I see right away, but I haven't had time to fully go over your answer yet

1. Your `</form>` tag is before your submit button
2. You generally want to to serialize the form on the `submit` event

   ```
   $("form").submit(function(event) {

     var obj = $(this).serializeObject();
     console.log(obj);

     var json = $(this).serializeJSON();
     console.log(json);

     event.preventDefault();
   });
   ```

   This way you will be serializing the values *after* a user has filled it in.

   However, we need to make a slight modification to this because you're dynamically creating the forms. We need to use a "live" listener with jQuery's [.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) function

   ```
   $("document").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
     // ...
   });
   ```

   This will attach a single submit event listener to the document, but it will be triggered by any form that bubbles up a submit event. This means that it will work for forms that are dynamically created after page load, too.

Comment: Although my question has already been answered, thank you for your help and your time, your tips gave me a deeper insight of how the js 'logic' works, I will have to look into it more. Good luck with your tests!

Comment: @Eimantas, I've updated my answer to show how to serialize to JSON directly. This has been fixed in the latest release of [jquery-serialize-object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object).